The Uniqueness of the Logarithm as a Group Isomorphism between the Positive Reals and Reals
My Group Theory textbook asks of me that I prove the following statement:

If $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any isomorphism between the groups $(\mathbb{R}^{+}, \cdot)$, $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ (here $\mathbb{R}^{+} := (0; +\infty)$), then $\exists a > 0: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}: \varphi(x) = \log_{a}(x)$.

Essentially, it is asked that I shew that if a function $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bijective and if it satisfies the functional equation $\varphi(xy) = \varphi(x) + \varphi(y)$ for all $x, y > 0$, then it is necessarily a logarithm. I am somewhat at a loss with this proposition. I do recognise that if there was put upon $\varphi$ some ancillary condition, such as continuity over its domain, the statement would be all but trivial. But the condition of being bijective seems to me very weak, much weaker than any other, specially continuity. I have tried for some hours to prove the result, but to no avail, as I keep running up into difficulties regarding irrationals (I have shewed that at all the positive rational points the function $\varphi$ must be identical to some logarithm with a fixed base, easy stuff, but as of yet I see no adequate way of passing over to the irrationals).
What I wish to know is whether the statement is actually correct and worth proving (i.e. it is not a typo or anything), specially since it is one of the first problems from the whole textbook, and therefore I think it is supposed to be doable. If it is true, then I should be very thankful if you could provide some hints towards a solution.
Or it may be that I am just being dense, who knows.
EDIT: My proof of the fact that $\varphi$ is the inverse of some exponential function whose exponents are rational:
The argument is this: since $\varphi$ is bijective, there is a unique $\xi > 0$ such that $\varphi(\xi) = 1$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have from the functional equation that $\varphi(\xi^{n}) = n\varphi(\xi) = n$. Notice from this that $\xi \neq 1$, otherwise a contradiction to bijectivity. Also from the equation we see that $0 = \varphi(1) = \varphi(x \cdot 1/x) = \varphi(x) + \varphi(x^{-1})$, whence $\varphi(x^{m}) = m$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now let $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $1 = \varphi(\xi) = \varphi(\xi^{p/p}) = p\varphi(\xi^{1/p})$, whence $\varphi(\xi^{1/p}) = 1/p$. Combining this with the aforementioned, we have $\varphi(\xi^r) = r$ for all $r \in \mathbb{Q^{+}}$.

What's the name of the textbook?

Let $a \in \mathbb R^+$ be such that $\varphi(a)=1$.  Show $\varphi(a^n)=n$ for positive integers $n$ ... for all integers $n$ ... for all rationals $n$ ... for all reals $n$.

@GEdgar: this simply does not work without further hypotheses (e.g. continuity, monotonicity, measurability).

True, I was thinking "monotonic".

@QiaochuYuan It’s a university textbook, not really known anywhere aside from, well, my university (written by our professors)

I've seen introductory calculus textbooks that define that any function is continuous (and then go on to prove theorems like 'all functions are Riemann integrable'). Possibly your textbook uses such a convention as well and with this convention the statement is correct. (This is a terrible convention from my perspective but that is besides the point).

@quarague Oh God I want to puke hearing about this convention lmao

This is false without more hypotheses on $\varphi$, e.g. it suffices to require that $\varphi$ is continuous, or monotonic, or measurable. Without any hypotheses we can compose $\varphi$ with pathological solutions to the Cauchy functional equation $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$, which can be obtained using the axiom of choice to find a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

(I have shewed that at all the positive rational points the function $\varphi$ must be identical to some logarithm with a fixed base, easy stuff, but as of yet I see no adequate way of passing over to the irrationals).

This is also false! Actually the behavior of $\varphi$ on different primes can be totally arbitrary; this is a consequence of the uniqueness of prime factorization (together with the axiom of choice). It is also true that the behavior of $\varphi$ on the rationals does not constrain its behavior on the irrationals at all.
(What's true is that the behavior of $\varphi^{-1}$ on the rationals is determined by its behavior on $1$.)

Okay, I get it, but where am I wrong with the bracketed comment? From the functional equation it follows directly, it so seems, just by considering multiples of arguments.

@Barbatulka: multiples of what? Write it out more carefully; what is your actual proof?

Added as an edit my proof

@Barbatulka: your proof is fine but it does not prove what you said it proves! You do in fact have $\varphi(\xi^r) = r$ for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$. This subset ${ \xi^r : r \in \mathbb{Q}^{+} }$ is not $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$!

God I see, I was only looking at the implications. Yes, indeed, I formulated the result wrongfully, but if I manage to shew the same for irrational exponents, then I will be justified in saying that $\varphi$ is the inverse of the exponential $\xi^x$ over all the reals. A brainfart on my part, thanks.

Another question: would these pathological solutions be bijective?

@Barbatulka: yes, they can be made bijective. For example you can permute a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ arbitrarily.
